# Exclude log4j.properties in the generated jar

Tags: maven, log4j

I am using `maven-compiler-plugin` to build a JAR from one of my module, and I am not able to exclude `log4j.properties` from the generated JAR.

I tried:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But this does not work. I can exclude the file globally:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

But I don't want to do this as this impact the Eclipse build, and makes it impossible to run code from Eclipse that uses log4j.

I tried to see if the included `log4j.properties` was mine and not from another module, and it is mine. I've read numerous posts on the issue, including some here, but I still cannot solve it...

If this matters, this module is a submodule of a parent package, with the following `<build>`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <show>private</show>
                <nohelp>true</nohelp>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-javadoc</id>
                    <phase>javadoc</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javadoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```